# .stack().value_counts() across multiple columns treating same string value as a unique value instead of counting them as same

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Working with Survey data that has multiple responses in a List in a single column. Splitting it on a comma delimiter I was able to expand() the column into multiple columns of categorical data per individual response. For some reason I am struggling with .stack().value_counts()

Before calling `.stack().value_counts()` function

```
Data Frame Example:
    index    col1        col2
    0        tomato      potato
    1        chicken     tomato
```

When using `df.stack().value_counts()` I would expect the count of `tomato to be 2` given the output of the command.

```
index     stacked_col
0         tomato
          potato
1         chicken
          tomato



count
tomato 2
potato 1
chicken 1
```

For some reason I'm getting a `count of tomato 1, tomato 1, potato 1, chicken 1` in my pie chart.

```
 count
 tomato 1
 tomato 1
 potato 1
 chicken 1
```

`Note:` I used `str.strip()` and `str.lower()`, but I think I am missing something related to how `value_counts()` behaves when counting string values across different columns.

Comment: What is output of `df.stack().value_counts().unique()` ?

Comment: Using pandas 2.0 I can't reproduce this; I get `tomato     2 potato     1 chicken    1`

Comment: @PandaKim I figured it out.  For some reason the .strip() that I applied didn't take.  I had to go through column by column and strip each value.  It's now behaving as expected.

I used len(string) to debug the issue on the values I expected to be identical. {Face Palm} - invested 4 hrs googling and stacking. Won't make this mistake again.